# Netty Webclient memory leak in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

Hi all we are seeing app crash under heavy load when we analyze our heap dump major memory is taken by netty below the following leak suspect

```
218,618,256 bytes (63.15 %) of Java heap is used by 24 instances of io/netty/buffer/PoolArena$HeapArena
 Contains 12 instances of the following leak suspects:
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x711b00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x710a00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x70ea00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x708500000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x70d900000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x70c800000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x71ea00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x716c00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x715900000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x705c00000
 - byte[] holding 16,777,224 bytes at 0x704b00000
 - io/netty/buffer/PoolChunk holding 33,609,288 bytes at 0x71d476ad8
```

we are using only 6 instance of webclient why it is showing 12 instance? why it is not releasing memory? can anyone guide us on this.

WebClient request

```java
    public <T> Mono<T> sendGetRequest(String apiBaseUrl, String apiEndpoint, String queryParams, HttpHeaders headers, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> params) {
            return webClient.get()
                    .uri(apiBaseUrl + apiEndpoint, params).headers(getHttpHeaders(headers))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(clazz);
        }
```

Comment: can you share how you use webclient? maybe you don't release resources property?

Comment: @pixel i have updated the how we use webclient

Comment: Adding -Dio.netty.allocator.type=unpooled showed significant reduction in the memory and performance both with and unpooled performance similar

Answer (score 1):

This memory is allocated by netty and it's not a leak. See similar question: [Memory accumulated in netty PoolChunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452332/memory-accumulated-in-netty-poolchunk)